# Change the type on a Subclass property

Tags: c#

I'm unsure how I would do this.  I have a common base class that is a DTO that has the majority of the properties I need. This class has some properties that are base classes too.

I want to be able to have additional properties depending on the circumstance:

E.g

```
 public class BaseOrder
 {
     //Other common properties
     public List<BaseItem> Items { get; set; }
 }
 
 public class BaseItem
 {
     //Properties to do with an Item
 }
 
 public class AdminOrder: BaseOrder
 {
     // THIS IS THE KEY PART: I want Items to be a list of type AdminItem
     public List<AdminItem> Items { get; set; }
 }
 
 public class AdminItem:BaseItem
 {
     //Properties to do with an Item AND Admin stuff too
 }
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Are you able to use generic arguments on the classes?

Comment: I want Items to be a list of type AdminItem --- isn't it currently a list of type AdminItem? any compile error?

Comment: @LeiYang yes, but without hiding the inherited member.

Comment: A `List<AdminItem>` **doesn't** even derive from `List<BaseItem>`. The inheritance relationships don't "carry over" into generics parameterised on those types. And even if they did, what happens when some code assigns something to the `Items` property of a `BaseOrder` variable that *happens to currently reference* an `AdminOrder`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public class BaseOrder<TYPE> where TYPE: BaseItem
 {
     //Other common properties
     public List<TYPE> Items { get; set; }
 }
 
 public class BaseItem
 {
     //Properties to do with an Item
 }
 
 public class AdminOrder: BaseOrder<AdminItem>
 {
 }
 
 public class AdminItem:BaseItem
 {
     //Properties to do with an Item AND Admin stuff too
 }
```

Comment: Deleted mine as you answered as I was editing mine to take into account the `BaseOrder` class.

Comment: Maybe  remove the `Items` def in the `AdminOrder` class though (or at least comment it out) since it is actually declared in the base class.

Answer (score 3):

Use generic arguments for the `BaseOrder` class to specify the type of the `Items` property, and limit it to a type that is or inherits from `BaseItem`.

You can then remove the property completely in AdminOrder, because it's inherited with the type specified in the generic arguments.

```
 public class BaseOrder<TItem> where TItem : BaseItem
 {
     //Other common properties
     public List<TItem> Items { get; set; }
 }
 
 public class BaseItem
 {
     //Properties to do with an Item
 }
 
 public class AdminOrder: BaseOrder<AdminItem>
 {
     // No need to define Items again here!
 }
 
 public class AdminItem:BaseItem
 {
     //Properties to do with an Item AND Admin stuff too
 }
```

You don't *need* to have `with TItem : BaseItem`, but it helps enforce choosing the right type in AdminOrder.

Also optional, you may consider making `BaseOrder` abstract, if you don't want a `BaseOrder` object directly being created - you only expect a type that inherits from BaseOrder.